# How to redirect an URL to a parent iframe

Tags: php, javascript

Im trying to redirect an user of my page when I ban him from my chat box using this (php):

```
header("location: index.php");
exit;
```

The problem is the **index.php** page is opening inside the connected users section, in this case inside a `div`. How can i redirect the user's main page ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: rather than redirecting in the frame, you could use `die("You have been banned");` instead of `header()`. The other option is to have a ajax/java call to check on if a redirect is needed

Comment: I just tried `die("banned");` everything inside the connected users div got erased so its actually the same problem, somehow i need to do that in the parent document.
I dont know about ajax hehehe

Comment: Do you have the parent page check if the user is banned?

Comment: Ummm, good idea, i can put a check in the parent page and refresh it when i ban someone but the next question is: How to tell an specific page to refresh in php or javascript

Comment: This may depend on what the page is used for, if a refresh occurs often, then the check will happen but if the user never refreshes you need to intervene. One way is to use java to make a check so often against the server or make the page refresh with (HTML header) `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="($seconds)">`. This could get annoying to some.

Comment: Yeah, especially because is a chat box, so if someone is tipping and then his message get erased would be very frustating. So i need to find another solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the answer using javascript:

```
window.parent.location = "http://www.example.com/index.php";
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this in the javascript code:

```
window.top.location.href = "http://www.site.com";
```

Comment: Im not sure about the differences between both answers, but it worked too.